# Communities licensing for employees

Tags: community

Do I have to purchase Communities licenses in order to use communities to create an Intranet to be accessed only be my employees who already have Salesforce licenses?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

i don't think you just need to add their profile in community. If they are your existing user.

Also SF provide free community to you don't need to purchase any additional license.

Comment: If I wanted to create my own internal community, would I need community licenses?

Comment: no if you want to create community user then you will need license. if your internal user want to use community. You just need to add their profile in the community profile .

Comment: So If I got a license for one user to create the community, I could build it and then add the other users to it without buying licenses for all users?

Comment: you don't need user license to build community. You already have one or more available community.